# collection_select not selecting value when it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a collection of ParsingTeams.  Each ParsingTeam has an associated Team.  I'm trying to create dropdown boxes for each ParsingTeam and where the associated Team already exists, I want that team to be selected.  I can generate the dropdown but no values ever get selected.  Here's my code:

```
<ul class="recent-posts">
  <% @parsingteams.each do |team| %>
    <li>
      <span class="user-info"><h5><%= team.teamname %></h5></span>
      <%= collection_select(team, "team_id", @teams, :id, :teamname) %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I've tried several variations of the object and method for the collection_select with no luck.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your form?

Comment: So you want multiple select boxes? One for each team? What would the individual options of the teams[n] select be? Is there a team.members association in your model that we can use to find the options for the select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need use the selected option and pass in the value you want to be selected by default. 
Check out nachocab's post on  [this article](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)

Comment: You could add a piece of code as an example: `collection_select(team, :team_id, @teams, :id, :teamname, selected: team.id)`

Comment: This worked perfectly.  My code became  <%= collection_select(team, "team_id", @teams, :id, :teamname, {:selected => team.team_id} ) %>

Answer (score 0):

To use the `collection_select`, you need:

An object

A field on that object that's "bound" the the value that gets selected

A collection of all the possible values that could get selected

A text label for each possible value

So if you are making multiple selects here, you would have two collections involved, one would have one member for each team. The other would have a member for each option in the select boxes. The 3rd argument of the collection_select method is the one that has all possible options.